# Retrieve Data from design view in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to extract all the information from the design view in Access. It can be quite cumbersome to manually copy and paste field names and data types, especially when dealing with tables that have a large number of fields. Is there a more convenient method to address this issue? Ideally, I would like to have a table that lists all the field names and data types in a tabular format, like the example below:

| Count | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | Text |
| 2 | Second | Number |
| 3 | Third | Text |

etc.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you for any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: Why would you need to copy field names? Might find field names in hidden system tables https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/purpose-of-system-tables.300451/. Otherwise, the "way" is with a bunch of VBA to pull table properties. Actually a fairly common topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can print out (or view) the tables as a report.

Use the documenter

Like this:

[image]

Just MAKE SURE you select the option for "Names, data types and sizes".

If you use the default settings, you have to load up your printer with a hole ream of paper!!! (the output will NOT be columnar - and you get 100's of pages of documentation output).

So, you can use the database documenter to print out code, reports, forms or whatever. And as above shows, you can print out (or view) one table, or select them all.

So try one table - play around with the "option" as I did above. Play until you find a output that you like, and then you can output all tables.

As noted, be careful, since if you don't play with + set those options, you get 100's and 100's of pages of output (and they will not be in columnar format for the table documentation).

Of course I will in some cases just highlight a table, hit ctrl-c (to copy), then ctrl-v to paste. You get a option to ONLY paste the table structure (without data). Then I delete all the columns I don't want for the new table - no need to create all the columns manually.